# Undefined method - fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

Overnight my website has decided to produce the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Error::get_items() in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions.php on line 494

The error breaks the twitter feed which stops the rest of the page rendering. I didn't implement the code for this site, but the code thats upsetting things appears to be:

```
function twitterify($ret) {

$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $ret);
$ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $ret);
return $ret;
}
```

Which has been pulled from [this website](http://www.snipe.net/2009/09/php-twitter-clickable-links/#axzz0psFrJPHB).

Any ideas as to how this could be resolved? I hear that Twitter has changed their API, could this be the issue?

Comment: this code snippet does not make the a call to the function you showed in the error. Why don't you show us line 494 and the relevant code?

Comment: Line 494 is in the middle of commented code..

Comment: But this is the code from that line through to the next function: 
 * @return string The gallery style filter, with the styles themselves removed.

 */

function twentyten_remove_gallery_css( $css ) {

 return preg_replace( "#<style type='text/css'>(.*?)</style>#s", '', $css );

}

Comment: maybe you can show the commented code? like say "this is line 494"?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have something to do with an RSS fetch_feed() function.  When fetch_feed() is successful, it returns a SimplePie class that has a method of get_items().  **However, if fetch_feed fails, it returns a WP_Error class, that DOES NOT have a method of get_items(), and now you're calling an undefined function.**

This might look like:

```
$rss = fetch_feed($url);
$rss->get_items();
```

In this example, $rss will be a WP_Error class if the fetch_feed() function fails...

Comment: Cheers Mike, I'm new to PHP but that still makes sense. Looking at the code I've found the following rss feed: "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'.$username.'.rss" but this looks to be a retired API. I'll amend to "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=user-name-here" and see if its able to fetch the feed.